# Banco de Dados pode sobrecarregar dessa maneira?

Tags: mysql, banco-de-dados, codeigniter

Essa explicação não há necessidade de código, é mais uma questão de lógica de banco de dados mesmo. O que está acontecendo:

Tenho uma aplicação usando CodeIgniter e MySql, e ela tem 4 atores, mas em um destes atores, quanto mais você *loga*, mais demora a carregar. Parece que quanto mais eu *logo*, mais o banco fica "sobrecarregado" (o que não acontece com os outros atores, e inclusive tem dois que trazem muitos mais relacionamentos no banco do que este).

Por exemplo, *loguei* uma vez ele leva em torno de 5-7 segundos pra carregar a página principal. Se eu *deslogar* e *logar* novamente ele vai levar em torno de 10 segundos e assim sucessivamente (até o ponto de ficar praticamente "*inlogável*" de tanta demora).
Não é questão de código pois fiz uma função que retornava práticamente nada (apenas a *view* com html básico), e demorou mesmo assim.

Detalhe importante: No meu local não acontece isso, sempre carrega rápido.

Comment: Confira se as tabelas estão como innoDB. Esta propriedade é típica para manipulação com leitura e gravação de dados. Enquanto o isan é mais para leitura de dados.

Comment: Verifique se existe alguma transação aberta.

Comment: Sim sim, está em innoDB.

Comment: Por acaso já conseguiu resolver, se sim qual foi a solução e o que era?

Comment: Não, na vdd dei uma revisada no código e consegui dar uma amenizada na situação. Mas continua com a "sobrecarga" só que de uma maneira menos preocupante